# How to embed a responsive iframe of a plotly graph?

Tags: html, css, iframe, plotly, responsive

I'm trying to embed a plotly pie chart in a [webpage](http://www.vipinajayakumar.com/managing-your-money/). I wanted the iframe to be responsive, so I used [this tool](http://embedresponsively.com) to generate the html/css for it. The result looks fine on a laptop, however on my phone in portrait mode, I can hardly see the pie chart. How can I fix it, so that the pie chart looks big and visible on whatever screen.

**Here is the code:**

```
<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%;      
height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, 
.embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute;   
top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'>
<iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' 
src='//plot.ly/~bluprince13/3.embed?autosize=true&link=false&modebar=false&width=100%'></iframe></div>
```

**And the screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot of webpage from phone]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that's how embed responsive works... It's goes on until there is nothing left... However (my method might not be the most optimal), I used min-width and min-height to stall the size reduction after a set width... Check this out:

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZMJER?editors=1100

```
div {
  min-width: 280px;
  min-height: 280px;
}
```

Also, you can use Bootstrap's embed-responsive for iframe instead of the css code... Just a suggestion...

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='//plot.ly/~bluprince13/3.embed?autosize=true&link=false&modebar=false&width=100%' class="embed-responsive-item" style="border:none;" ></iframe>
</div>
```